# Zend Framework plugin autoloading

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have been trying to write a Controller Plugin which I will be using for user authentication.
I have written the plugin and it should work but I just don't get how to get the plugin loaded... I have read that the Zend Framework has a lot of autoloading possibilities..

My current directory structure:

```
domains
example.com
    Application
        configs
        controllers
            IndexController.php
            AuthController.php
            ErrorController.php
        forms
        layouts
            scripts
                layout.phtml
        models
        plugins
            AuthenticationPlugin.php
        views
            helpers
            scripts
                auth
                    login.phtml
                error
                    error.phtml
                index
                    index.phtml
        Bootstrap.php
    library
        Zend
    pubic_html
        .htaccess
        index.php
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `appnamespace` is `Application_`, then your plugin class should be:

1. named `Application_Plugin_AuthenticationPlugin`
2. stored in the file `application/plugins/AuthenticationPlugin.php`
3. registered with the frontcontroller using something like (in `application/configs/application.ini`):

   `resources.frontController.plugins.auth = "Application_Plugin_AuthenticationPlugin"`

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own library folder with a similar folder structure to Zend's. For instance (assuming your own namespace `My_`):

```
library
  My
    Controller  
      Plugin
        Authentication.php
```

`Authentication.php` would contain a class named `My_Controller_Plugin_Authentication`.

You would then register the namespace in your bootstrap ([manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html)):

```
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$autoloader->registerNamespace('My_');
```

Failing that, you could use the structure above using the resource autoloader ([manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html)). Zend Framework expects that classes in those folders are namespace prefixed too, so your class name would be `Plugin_AuthenticationPlugin`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line in for example your Bootstrap file:

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->registerPlugin(new AuthenticationPlugin());
```

Comment: Then I get the message that the AuthenticationPlugin class cannot be found...

Can I create another directory in the Library directory and work with plugins over there?

Comment: Your directory structure is OK. Inside AuthenticationPlugin.php, try renaming your class to Zend_Plugin_AuthenticationPlugin, and change the above line to `Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->registerPlugin(new Zend_Plugin_AuthenticationPlugin());`

Comment: I'd advise against placing custom app/lib classes within the `Zend_` namespace. Better I think to name them in an appnamespace or a separate lib namespace.